# Javascript libraries for touch devices like iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, javascript

I need to make an important decision regarding selecting the right js framework for my web app. It is going to be the same html running on multiple devices..desktop, tabke, mobile..

As of now, we need to support iPad and iPhone to some extent with possibility to support Android tablet in future...

My question is apart from Sencha touch,which are some other good js libraries ?
I know Sencha touch is good, but not really sure how to convince the client about that, if the same thing can be done via jQuery related libraries..

My page would have standard touch related things like swipe, drag and drop, accordion related things...

Please suggest which library should i go for..like which are optimized for touch devices..
I have heard jQuery mobile is there, but not sure if it is mature enough and good for professional use..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery Mobile** is still in beta but it's powerful yet. **Sencha** is perfect, many good apps done with that.

Basically a library mostly used for touch event handleng, ajaxing and UI. Sencha have them all.

If you want to take a look at other libraries here is some:

- Titanium (Native)
- PhoenGap(Native)
- Sproutcore Touch
- iUI
- jQPad

Comment: I am omly looking at web based ones not native...also some like jQPad do not open their web site correctly...